# Javascript replace does not work only in IE

Tags: javascript, replace

This code work greate in any browser (included IE)

```
document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML += document.getElementById('prod1').innerHTML+"< br >";
```

But when I try remove this same substring using IE, it does not work! In Firefox or Chorme works OK.

```
 var text=document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML =  text.replace(document.getElementById('prod1').innerHTML+"< br >","");
```

IE does not recognize the substring with < br > ? 
I tried without  < br >  tag and IE works correctly, but I need to be able to add and remove spaces in my HTML element.
using Firefox or Chorme it's replaced with no problem.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't add a RegExp object or // around your regex.

Comment: @WouterJ: It's not a regular expression. The `replace` method also works with a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property doesn't have to return the exact string that you assign to it. Some browsers do, but IE doesn't.

In IE when you read the property, the HTML code is constructed from the elements in the DOM, not from the HTML code that was used to create the elements. In IE you will get back `<BR>` even if you use `<br>` in the HTML code to create the element. That could be solved with a case insensetive replace, but the same applies to the elements inside `prod1`, which might not be as simple to solve depending on what the code looks like.

You should rather add/remove elements in the DOM instead of manipulating HTML. When you use `+=` and `replace` on the `innerHTML` property, you will be converting the elements to HTML, then create new elements again, including all the elements in the `solicit` element that you don't change. You might consider using a library like jQuery, which makes it a lot easier to manipulate elements.

Answer (score 0):

View source and you might see 
`<BR>`

so add a ,"i" to the replace to ignore case - and possibly a regex to handle the missing white space in the result tag

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!
Knowing the information that you passed me by saying that IE interprets the < br > as < BR > I was only able to develop this solution:

```
 var text=document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML;
 if (navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer')     
 document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML = text.replace(document.getElementById('prod1').innerHTML+"<BR>","");
 else
 document.getElementById('solicit').innerHTML = text.replace(document.getElementById('prod1').innerHTML+"<br>","");
```

With this browse verification my code works correctly. But I'm sure my solution is not the most "elegant" as possible.
Is there any other alternative using only javascript?

Thanks again